# Count iterations

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

How can i find on this iteration while loop how many iterations were needed until the condition was no longer satisfied.How many iterations were rejected and how many were accepted?

```
a=2
b=2
n=10000
M=1.5
X = 0
AR = rep(NA,n)
set.seed(12345)
while (X < n) {
  u = runif(1,0,1)
  y = runif(1)
  if (u < dbeta(y,2,2)/(M*dunif(y,0,1))) { 
    X = X+1
    AR[X] = y
  }
}
AR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add counter variables:

```
a=2
b=2
n=10000
M=1.5
X = 0
AR = rep(NA,n)
set.seed(12345)
i1 <- i2 <- 0
while (X < n) {
  i1 <- i1 + 1
  u = runif(1,0,1)
  y = runif(1)
  if (u < dbeta(y,2,2)/(M*dunif(y,0,1))) { 
    i2 <- i2 + 1
    X = X+1
    AR[X] = y
  }
}
AR

i1
i2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another counter `iter` for the iterations, e.g.,

- with `while`

```
iter <- 0
while (X < n) {
  iter <- iter + 1
  u = runif(1,0,1)
  y = runif(1)
  if (u < dbeta(y,2,2)/(M*dunif(y,0,1))) {
    X = X+1
    AR[X] = y
  }
}
```

- with `repeat`

```
iter <- 0
repeat {
  if (X==n) break
  iter <- iter + 1
  u = runif(1,0,1)
  y = runif(1)
  if (u < dbeta(y,2,2)/(M*dunif(y,0,1))) { 
    X = X+1
    AR[X] = y
  }
}
```